# Pythonish integer range in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

Python has that `range`:

> >>> range(10, -20, -3)
> [10, 7, 4, 1, -2, -5, -8, -11, -14, -17]

I have this C++ implementation of exactly the same facility:

**range.h**:

```
/* 
 * File:    range.h
 * Author:  Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * Version: (Nov 30, 2015)
 */

#ifndef RANGE_H
#define RANGE_H
#include <stdexcept>

namespace coderodde {

    template<typename Int = int>
    class range {
    private:
        Int m_start;
        Int m_end;
        Int m_step;

        class range_iterator {
        private:
            Int    m_value;
            Int    m_step;
            size_t m_count;

        public:
            range_iterator(Int value, 
                           Int step, 
                           size_t count) : m_value{value}, 
                                           m_step{step},
                                           m_count{count} {}

            int  operator*() { return m_value; }
            bool operator!=(range_iterator& other) { return m_count != other.m_count; }
            void operator++() { m_value += m_step; ++m_count; }
        };

    public:
        range(Int start, Int end, Int step) : m_start{start},
                                              m_end{end},
                                              m_step{step} {}

        range(Int start, Int end) : range(start, end, 1) {}

        range_iterator begin() { return range_iterator(m_start, m_step, 0); }

        range_iterator end() { 
            if (m_step == 0) throw std::runtime_error("The step is zero.");

            if (m_start <= m_end) 
            {
                if (m_step < 0) 
                {
                    return range_iterator(0, 0, 0);
                }

                return range_iterator(m_start, m_step, 
                                     (m_end - m_start) / m_step + 
                                   (((m_end - m_start) % m_step) ? 1 : 0));
            }
            else 
            {
                if (m_step > 0) 
                {
                    return range_iterator(0, 0, 0);
                }

                m_step = -m_step;
                return range_iterator(m_start, m_step, 
                                     (m_start - m_end) / m_step +
                                   (((m_start - m_end) % m_step) ? 1 : 0));
            }
        } 
    };
}

#endif  /* RANGE_H */
```

With demo **main.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "range.h"

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using coderodde::range;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    while (true)
    {
        int start = 0;
        int end   = 0;
        int step  = 0;

        cout << ">> ";

        if (not (cin >> start >> end >> step)) 
        {
            break;
        }

        try 
        {
            for (auto i : range<>(start, end, step)) 
            {
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        } 
        catch (std::runtime_error& err)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << err.what() << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "Bye!" << endl;
}
```

I tried hard to make my `range` act exactly the same way is in Python (2.7). For instance, if `step` is 0, an exception is thrown.

I do not have much experience in C++, so any critique is much appreciated.

Comment: I would add a template function: `make_range()`. That way you can use template type-deduction provided by functions to automatically get the correctly typed version of `range` without having the ugly `<>` at the end. `for (auto i : make_range(start, end, step))`

Comment: Actually, this seems more of a Python 2.7 `xrange` rather than `range`.  That's not a problem, but worth noting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Keeping a Count**

You implemented `range_iterator` to keep a count which you use for equality comparisons. This works, but involves a really awkward formula for getting the count right. Instead, it would be simpler to just round `end` to be one past the last one, so that `range(0, 11, 2)` sets `start` to `0` and `end` to `12`. This would make `range_iterator` only require two members, and `operator!=` to just compare the `m_value`'s.

**Wrong Type**

`range_iterator` dereferences to `int`, but should be `Int`.

**Usage**

This is awkward:

```
for (auto i : range<>(start, end, step)) 
//                 ^^^
```

Rather than having it be up to the user to provide the correct type, you could instead take advantage of template deduction:

```
template <typename Int>
Range<Int> range(Int start, Int end, Int step) { ... }
```

You'll have to rename your class template to get this to work. Even better would be to make the function a `friend` of the class, and make the constructors private.

**Keep `begin()` and `end()` simple**

Once we rewrite `range()` to be a function template that returns an object, you can move all of the logical checking into it:

```
template <typename Int>
Range<Int> range(Int start, Int end, Int step) {
    if (step == 0) throw ...;

    if (start <= end) {
       if (step < 0) {
           return {0,0,0};
       }
       return {start, (end + step - 1) / step * step};
    }
    else {
       // etc.
    }
}
```

This means that `begin()` just returns `range_iterator{m_start, m_step}` and `end()` just returns `range_iterator{m_end, m_step}`.

**Other Overloads**

Python also allows for something like `range(10)`, so that's just:

```
template <class Int>
Range<Int> range(Int end) {
    return {0, end, 1};
}
```

**Iterator Interface**

Even though it won't be fully utilized in the simple example of `for (auto i : range(10))`, you should prefer to provide a complete interface for `range_iterator`. You're missing `operator==` and postfix-increment. Prefix-increment (and postfix-increment) should return references to this.

Additionally, you should inherit from `std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int, std::ptrdiff_t, int, int>` just in case somebody wants to use `range()` as a normal container somewhere else.

For example, it'd be nice to support the following:

```
auto r = range(10);
std::vector<int> v(r.begin(), r.end());
```

which currently will fail to compile.

Comment: Dislike the word `should` in `Additionally, you should inherit from`. Though this is the easiest way its not the only way. I would prefer `could`. But you also need a paragraph describing the requirements for iterators (as currently apart from the name his iterators do not conform to the `concept` of an iterator) then you can say the best way to implement the requirements is by inheriting from `std::iterator<>`

Comment: I don't understand how to get rid of `range<>` and use only `range` instead. Any help?

Comment: @coderodde What part didn't you understand?

Comment: @Barry The second code snippet in the __Usage__ section.

Comment: @coderodde I made `range` a function template that returns a `Range<Int>` - template deduction picks up what `Int` is, so you don't have to provide it.