# Pythonish integer range in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, iterator

(See the [previous iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/112461/pythonish-integer-range-in-java).)

I have refactored the `Range`; now it looks like this:

**Range.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.AbstractCollection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This class implements an iterator over an arithmetic progression of integers.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 1, 2015)
 */
public class Range extends AbstractCollection<Integer>
implements Iterable<Integer> {

    private final int start;
    private final int step;
    private final int stop;

    public static Range range(int start, int stop, int step) {
        return new Range(start, stop, step);
    }

    public static Range range(int start, int stop) {
        return new Range(start, stop, 1);
    }

    public static Range range(int end) {
        return new Range(0, end, 1);
    }

    private Range(int start, int stop, int step) {
        if (step == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Step argument must not be zero.");
        }

        this.start = start;
        this.step  = step;
        this.stop  = stop;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new RangeIterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return Math.max(0, step > 0 ? (stop + step - 1 - start) / step
                                    : (stop + step + 1 - start) / step);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        try {
            int n = (int)o;

            boolean inBounds = step > 0 ? (start <= n) && (n < stop)
                                        : (start >= n) && (n > stop);

            return inBounds && (n - start) % step == 0;
        } catch (ClassCastException oIsNotAnInt) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Removing from an integer Range is not supported.");
    }

    // Throw since if we inherit from AbstractCollection, it will not throw on 
    // empty collection as it will not call method 'add' (which throws).
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Bulk adding to integer Range is not supported.");
    }

    // Same reasoning as above with 'addAll'.
    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                "Bulk removing from integer Range is not supported.");
    }

    private final class RangeIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
        private int value = start;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return step > 0 ? value < stop : value > stop;  
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException(
                        "The range iterator exceeded.");
            }

            try {
                return value;
            } finally {
                value += step;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Range r = range(100, 9, -3);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(r);
        int j = 0;

        for (int i : r) {
            System.out.printf("%3d : %3d\n", i, list.get(j++));
        }
    }
}
```

**RangeTest.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static net.coderodde.util.Range.*;

public class RangeTest {

    @Test
    public void testRange_3args() {
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(range(37, -11, -5));
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        assertEquals(10, list.size());

        for (int i = 37, j = 0; i > -11; i -= 5, ++j) {
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(i), list.get(j));
        }

        Range r = range(10, 50, 7);

        assertTrue(r.contains(10));
        assertTrue(r.contains(17));
        assertTrue(r.contains(24));
        assertTrue(r.contains(31));
        assertTrue(r.contains(38));
        assertTrue(r.contains(45));

        assertEquals(6, r.size());

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = r.iterator();

        for (int i = 10; i < 50; i += 7) {
            assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(i), iterator.next());
        }

        assertFalse(iterator.hasNext());

        for (int i = -100; i < 10; ++i) {
            assertFalse(r.contains(i));
        }

        for (int i = 50; i < 100; ++i) {
            assertFalse(r.contains(i));
        }

        ////

        for (int step = -1; step > -10; --step) {
            r = range(5, 50, step);

            assertEquals(0, r.size());
            assertFalse(r.iterator().hasNext());
        }

        for (int step = 1; step < 10; ++step) {
            r = range(50, 5, step);

            assertEquals(0, r.size());
            assertFalse(r.iterator().hasNext());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRange_int_int() {
        Range r = range(10, 17);

        for (int i = 10; i < 17; ++i) {
            assertTrue(r.contains(i));
        }

        assertEquals(7, r.size());
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = r.iterator();

        for (int i = 10; i < 17; ++i) {
            assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(i), iterator.next());
        }

        assertFalse(iterator.hasNext());

        for (int i = -100; i < 10; ++i) {
            assertFalse(r.contains(i));
        }

        for (int i = 17; i < 100; ++i) {
            assertFalse(r.contains(i));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRange_int() {
        Range r = range(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            assertTrue(r.contains(i));
        }

        assertEquals(5, r.size());

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = r.iterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            assertTrue(iterator.hasNext());
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(i), iterator.next());
        }

        assertFalse(iterator.hasNext());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIterator() {
        Range r = range(50, 1, -3);

        assertEquals(17, r.size());
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = r.iterator();

        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(50), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(47), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(44), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(41), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(38), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(35), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(32), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(29), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(26), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(23), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(20), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(17), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(14), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(11), iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(8),  iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5),  iterator.next());
        assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(2),  iterator.next());

        assertFalse(iterator.hasNext());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        Range r = range(10, 2, -2);
        assertEquals(4, r.size());

        r = range(2, 10, 2);
        assertEquals(4, r.size());

        r = range(10, 2, 2);
        assertEquals(0, r.size());

        r = range(2, 10, -2);
        assertEquals(0, r.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsEmpty() {
        Range r = range(0);
        assertTrue(r.isEmpty());

        r = range(20, 33, 3);
        assertFalse(r.isEmpty());

        r = range(20, 33, -3);
        assertTrue(r.isEmpty());

        r = range(33, 20, -3);
        assertFalse(r.isEmpty());

        r = range(33, 20, 3);
        assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testContains() {
        Range r = range(10, 0, 2);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i += 2) {
            assertFalse(r.contains(i));
        }

        r = range(10, 1, -2);

        for (int i = 10; i > 1; i -= 2) {
            assertTrue(r.contains(i));
        }

        r = range(10, 0, -2);

        for (int i = 10; i > 0; i -= 2) {
            assertTrue(r.contains(i));
        }

        r = range(10, -1, -2);

        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            assertTrue(r.contains(i));
        }

        ////

        r = range(20, 50, 4);

        for (int i = 20; i < 50; i += 4) {
            assertTrue(r.contains(i));
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testToArray_0args() {
        Range r = range(-10, 10, 2);
        Object[] arr = r.toArray();

        assertEquals(10, arr.length);

        for (int i = 0, j = -10; i < arr.length; ++i, j += 2) {
            assertEquals(j, arr[i]);
        }

        r = range(10, -10, -2);
        arr = r.toArray();

        assertEquals(10, arr.length);

        for (int i = 0, j = 10; i < arr.length; ++i, j -= 2) {
            assertEquals(j, arr[i]);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testToArray_GenericType() {
        Range r = range(37, 21, -1);

        Integer[] input = new Integer[4];
        Integer[] array = r.toArray(input);

        assertFalse(input == array);
        assertEquals(r.size(), array.length);

        input = new Integer[50];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            input[i] = Integer.valueOf(-1);
        }

        array = r.toArray(input);

        assertTrue(array == input);
        assertNull(input[r.size()]);

        for (int i = r.size() + 1; i < input.length; ++i) {
            assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(-1), input[i]);
        }
    }

    public void testContainsAll() {
        Range r = range(20, 3, -3);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(20);
        set.add(14);
        set.add(11);
        assertTrue(r.containsAll(set));

        set.add(19);
        assertFalse(r.containsAll(set));
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testAdd() {
        range(10).add(1);
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testRemove() {
        range(10).remove(1);
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testAddAll() {
        range(2, 12).addAll(new HashSet<>());
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testRemoveAll() {
        range(2, 12).removeAll(new HashSet<>());
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testRetainAll() {
        range(2, 12).retainAll(Arrays.asList(1));
    }

    @Test(expected = UnsupportedOperationException.class)
    public void testClear() {
        range(5).clear();
    }
}
```

So the usage is still the same:

```
for (int i : range(10, -5, -3)) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(range(-5, 10, 3));
```

I did not however done anything related to `IntStream`. Am I improving this compared to the first iteration?

Answer (score 4):

#### Builder Method Names

It's probably a matter of taste, but `Range.range(1, 10);` and the other two overloaded calls looks a bit redundant. It would look better as `Range.of(1, 10);`, wouldn't it?

#### Constants

It's very nice that the three `int` fields are final, but `size()` method performs calculations on each invocation of the method (plus if `isEmpty()` is called!), to produce the same result repetitively.

There should be a `final int size` field, calculated in the constructor (I wouldn't recommend to use lazy patterns here).

#### contains(Object)

What will happen if it was called with `null` arg? A `NullPointerException`. Since the `ClassCastException` is caught, I'd vote to add the NullPointer there also.

However, there is an alternative for the `try-catch` block in this case:

```
public boolean contains(int n) {
  boolean inBounds = step > 0 ? (start <= n) && (n < stop)
                              : (start >= n) && (n > stop);
  return inBounds && (n - start) % step == 0;
}

@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return false;
}
```

#### Logic

According to the tests and the implementation, ranges like (1, 10, -1), (10, 1, 1) are considered as empty. This choice looks a bit weird, because these ranges have valid bounds, but the value of the `step` field is inconsistent with these bounds, making them senseless. I think that the constructor arguments should be validated, with an `IllegalArgumentException` thrown for such cases.

And what about ranges like (1, 10, 20), (10, 1, -20) ? Are they also empty?

If the current implementation does not correspond to a strict requirement, I'd suggest to define an *empty range* as a range where the `start` and the `stop` values are equal.

*P.S.* please remove the `main(args)` method from `Range` class. There is already `RangeTest` for that.

Answer (score 2):

The `RangeTest` is incomplete.

- It should have tests for ranges near `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
- How does `range(MAX - 1, MAX, 3)` behave?
- Does `range(MIN, MAX)` contain 0? Does it contain MIN? Does it contain MAX?
- Does `range(MIN, MAX, 5)` contain 0, 1, 2, 3, 4? Does it contain MIN? Does it contain MAX?
- Can the range be endless by accident?